# Producing for a direct sum $V = U \oplus W$ an endomorphism $P$ of $V$ s.t. $Im(P) = U$ and $\ker(P) = W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, direct-sum

I've been asked to prove this:

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and suppose that $V =
U \oplus W$, where $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$.

> Show that $Im(P)=U$ and $\ker(P)=W$ for some $P \in End(V )$.

Sorry if I come across as being a bit dense but doesn't the direct sum hold the property of being commutative?

How can we specifically say that $Im(P) = U$? Say we took the direct sum as $W \oplus U$. Then $Im(P) = W$?

Could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong and maybe point me in the right direction? Cheers!

And sorry again if the answer is very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct sum is commutative in the sense that there is a canonical isomorphism $U \oplus W \cong W \oplus U$. But that doesn't mean that a given endomorphism $P$ behaves w.r.t. the summands $U$ and $W$ in the same way.

As for the problem itself:

**Hint** We can decompose the matrix for $P$ (w.r.t. any adapted basis of $V$ adapted to the decomposition $V = U \oplus W$) into blocks, as
$$P := \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix},$$ so that for any $(u, w) \in U \oplus W$ we have
$$P\begin{pmatrix}u \\ w\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}u \\ w\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, what restrictions do our conditions $\ker P = W$ and $\text{im }P = U$ impose on the matrix blocks $A, B, C, D$?

> Since $\ker P = W$, for all $w \in W$ we must have $$0 = P\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ w\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}Bu \\ Dw\end{pmatrix},$$ and so $B = 0$, $D = 0$. On the other hand, since $\text{im }P = U$, for all $(u, w) \in U \oplus W$ we must have that $$P\begin{pmatrix}u \\ w\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}Au + Bw \\ Cu + Dw\end{pmatrix}$$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix}\ast \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, and so $C = 0$ and $D = 0$, and altogether we have $B = 0$, $C = 0$, $D = 0$. This last condition guarantees that $\text{im }P \subseteq U$, but we must ensure that equality holds, or equivalently, that $\text{rank }P = \dim U$. Now, $\text{rank }P = \text{rank }A$, so our condition is that $\text{rank }A = \dim U$; but $A$ is a square matrix of size $\dim U$, so $A$ must be invertible. Thus, the transformations with the given properties are exactly the ones of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $A$ has full rank. There is a special choice here, namely where $A$ is the identity matrix (of size $\dim U$). In this case, $P$ is nothing more than the canonical projection of $U \oplus W$ onto $U$.

Answer (score 0):

If $V = U \oplus W$, then not only can we find

- $P \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ such that $\operatorname{Im}(P) = U$ and $\ker P = W$, but it's also true, like you pointed out, that there's some
- $Q \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ such that $\operatorname{Im}(Q) = W$ and $\ker Q = U$.

It doesn't really matter which summand they wanted as the image and which as the kernel; just that there are certain maps that have certain properties, with respect to direct sums.

As for proving the theorem, I would look for a map of the form

$$Pv = \begin{cases}??, & v\in U \\ ??,& v \not\in U\end{cases}.$$

Then, what's the most natural place to send things in $U$?